# How can we identify websites failing after disabling 3P cookies in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have a list of websites. I want to create an automated solution that will iterate over the list and notify me of the total number of websites that are not functioning correctly after disabling third-party cookies in Google Chrome.

I have observed that some websites do not entirely load, and in some, a few elements fail to load, etc. Is it possible to create a Chrome extension that can read if a website is trying to access third-party cookies? I know that we can listen to response headers in Chrome extensions, so if third-party cookies are disabled can we expect a specific HTTP status code in the response headers?

Any other method to generalize the approach?

I tried collecting the total number of response headers for a site first with 3P cookies enabled and then with 3P cookies disabled, the idea is that with 3P cookies allowed, we should see more response headers, but this approach is not full-proof as some of the websites use Google Analytics and this can mess up the headers count